# Prove $|f(x) -f(y)| \le 1 \ \forall x,y$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
>
> 1. $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x-y| \ \forall x,y$
> 2. $f(1)=f(-1)$
>
> Prove $|f(x) -f(y)| \le 1  \ \forall x,y$

Making $y=0$ I get $|f(x) -f(0)| \le |x| \le 1$ but I cannot extend it to the required conclusion.

Comment: Assume that $|f(x)-f(y)|>1$ for some $x<y$. Prove that $x$ and $y$ have to be far from each other and therefore respectively close to $-1$ and $1$. Deduce a contradiction.

Comment: That's great, now from that what can you say about $|x-(-1)|+|y-1|$?

Comment: For homework problems I think it is more useful to give hints.

Comment: The point is not whether this is actually homework, it's about how elementary the solution is. If the solution is not too hard, then you will gain more if you can find it by yourself using a hint than if it is completely written down for you. Teaching a man how to fish is better than giving him a fish, no matter the age ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Hint : 
Let $x$, $y$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|>1$. From 1. it comes $|x-y|\geq|f(x)-f(y)|>1$, so without loss of generality we can suppose that $$x<0<y \tag{3}$$

In the other hand, 
\begin{align*}
1<|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)-f(1)+f(1)|&\leq |f(x)-f(1)|+|-f(y)+f(1)|\\
&=|f(x)-f(-1)|+|-f(y)+f(1)| \tag{from 2.}\\
&\leq |-1-x|+|1-y|
\end{align*}

Now, what do you think about the distances between $-1$ and $x$, $1$ and $y$, since $-1\leq x<0<y\leq 1$ and $|x-y|>1$ ?

Comment: what is for the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

Assume that $|f(x)-f(y)|>1$ for some $x<y$ and show that $$|x-y|>1\Longrightarrow |x-(-1)|+|y-1|<1$$
Then use the fact that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|= |f(x)-f(-1)+f(1)-f(y)|$$
implies $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(-1)|+|f(1)-f(y)|$$

Answer (score 2):

Try filling in the details of the following reasoning.

First note that for all $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying (1.) and (2.), any vertical translation of $f$'s graph, that is, any $\varphi : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto f(x) + c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, also satisfies (1.) and (2.). So we always can choose the convenient translation $\varphi(x) = f(x) - f(1)$. Thus $\varphi(-1) = \varphi(1) = 0$. Therefore without loss of generality we consider that $f$ satisfies (2.) with $f(-1) = f(1) = 0$.

Then from (1.) we obtain
$$ |f(x) - f(\pm1)| \le |x \pm 1| $$

And since $x \in [-1, 1]$
$$ |f(x)| \le 1 - |x|$$

Then
$$ \text{graph}(f) = \{(x, f(x)) : x \in [-1,1]\} \subseteq \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| + |y| \le 1 \} $$

Now let $m = \min\{f(x) : x \in [-1,1]\}$ and show that $\max\{f(x) : x \in [-1,1]\} \le 1 + m$. Therefore $f([-1,1]) \subseteq [m, m + 1]$, whence follows the claim.

See if you can interpret the following figure according to this reasoning.

[image: f's possible values]